# In Java, what does does the method signature Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> mean?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, what does does the method signature `Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>` means?

It is defining a generic enumeration type. I just don't know what the `?` means. It seems that it's saying that a new type is being defined and all the compiler needs to know is that the new type extends `ZipEntry`. Is that accurate?

This is the context of the code:

```
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipfile.entries(); 
        e.hasMoreElements(); fileNumber++) 
{
    // ...etc...
}
```

If I were to speak `Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>` in english, what would be said?

Thanks!

Comment: An enumeration of any type that extends ZipEntry.

Comment: The best recourse for you is to read a good tutorial on Generics.

Comment: @Marko: Yes you're probably right. A book about generics in Java anyway. Though, I do understand the concept of generics. This was more of a syntax question.

Comment: `Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>` is said as "Enumeration of unknown extends ZipEntry"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "an `Enumeration` of some definite, but unspecified type that extends `ZipEntry`".

See: [Upper Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) in Oracle's tutorial about generics, and [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: Ok, so this is indicating a type that already exists, specifically, it is not an anonymous type or anything like that?

Comment: @quakkels An anonymous type cannot be referred to, it has no name.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose so :-)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "anonymous type". It's an `Enumeration` of some unknown type, at least at this point in the source code the compiler won't know what the type is; it only knows that that type extends `ZipEntry`. When you call the method, the objects that it will enumerate ofcourse have some type, but you don't know in advance (at compile-time) what type that is.

Comment: I meant anonymous type in the C# sense. Though, that was a silly thought that I didn't think through very well.

Comment: So essentially, the object in this enumeration would need to be derived from `ZipEntry`. I think in C# you can just say `Enumeration<SomeType>` and you can put anything you want in there as long as it is derived from `SomeType`. It would seem that inheritance doesn't work the same way in Java.

Comment: Yes. In Java `Enumeration<ZipEntry>` would also work, also if the actual objects were of some subclass of `ZipEntry`.

Comment: @m0skit0 Anonymous types do have a name (I guess they're not really anonymous then are they) - it is the name of the enclosing class plus $ plus the index of which anonymous in that class it is  `com.mypakage.MyClass$1`. And they can be used to satisfy a generic bound

Comment: No, that's incorrect, the C# equivalent of this is `Enumeration<T> where T : SomeType`  This is not the same thing.  In this case all the elements of the Enumeration must be the *same* type (derived from `SomeType`), which is a stronger requirement than `Enumeration<SomeType>` makes.

Comment: @Bohemian But this really doesn't have anything to do specifically with anonymous types.

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks, I didn't know that. But still they have no name *properly* speaking (i.e. you can't reference them in your code).